# How can I use the += operator in PHP for a string?

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

How can I use the += operator for a string in PHP?

Below is a *Java* example:

```
String str = "";

str += "some value";
str += "some more values";
```

The above example concatenates and assign all values to the `str` object.

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are searching for [`.=`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$str = "";
$str .= "some value";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $str .= "some value"; 
 $str .= "some more values";
```

Comment: ´$´ are missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
$str = $str + "stuff";
```

Or:

```
$str .= "stuffsicles";
```