# File-writing script just creates an empty file named "0"

Tags: php, file, server-side, file-writing

When I write a file using PHP,

```php
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    $texttowrite = $_POST['articletext'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    // Illegal characters on Unix and Linux or any *nix server
    $illegal = array(" ", "?", "/", "\\", "*", "|", "<", ">", '"');
    // Legal characters
    $legal = array("-", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_");
    // Replace it!
    $newtitle = str_replace($illegal, $legal, $title);
    $newname = str_replace($illegal, $legal, $name);
    $filename = "content/" + $newtitle + "-" + $newname;
    $myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $texttowrite);
?>
```

> note: this program is supposed to read output and a file name from
> POST form data and write it to a server.

it just creates a file called "0" in the root directory of the server's file system. Is there anything that's going wrong?

No errors were generated by the compiler.

Comment: Debug.  Print the values of `$filename` just before the `fopen`.  Is that what you expect?  A bunch of prints will show you the values of each variables.  Since it is not a fatal error (i.e. no error in your logs), it is a logic error.

Comment: There is *definitely* a duplicate question somewhere among the 1,402,389 PHP questions  (probably from 2008), but it is not easy to find. Can someone find it? A similar question, but for the `+=` operator: *[How can I use the += operator in PHP for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476940)*

Comment: A duplicate (but it is ***not*** a canonical question. It is closed, but the close target is *not* at all the canonical question): *[Plus operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398760)*

Comment: For future reference, this question was discussed on Meta: [Why is a question about creating a file in PHP not about programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407683/12892553)

Comment: What is the (canonical) duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation in PHP is `.`, not `+`.

Comment: It would be better to find the (canonical) duplicate on Stack Overflow.